# can datagridview be used on the web application

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my web page, I used a gridview to display the data. the problem now is the gridview header is dynamic(i.e) it takes the current month and displays the last two months a header.Say like August and September. Everything works fine, but i couldn't do the sorting. As the sortexpression takes only the database field name(which is August and september for now). So one of my friend suggest to use the datagridview. And i have no idea about the datagridview or datagrid. and i dint get a sample code for using those. If u guys know any, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use OnSorting event in gridview, then sort it by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's a winform control. If you want to use the DataGrid, just look at some code samples - MSDN would be a good place to start. If that's not what you need, there are ready-made solutions out on the web you can try. Just gotta do some research.